# Rails 5, active records needed on every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i started ror about a month ago and i'm very close to finishing my first project.I have some models thats needed to be on every page since i use their data on navbar,dropdowns and footer(like products etc.).
The thing is i noticed that my app is loading way too much active records and i want to know if there is anyway to make some optimization.

I use before_action on ApplicationController to load these active records;

```
before_action :set_constants, except: %i[destroy]

 def set_constants
  @main_contents = MainContent.all
  @abouts = About.all
  @products = Product.all
  @services = Service.all
  @policies = Policy.all
  @comm = Communication.first
 end
```

I just want to know is this okay ? or is there another way to do this since i need these models on almost every page.

Comment: I don't know your app, but it sounds strange that you really need all the records from five models everywhere.

Comment: I use them on dropdowns like Products->Product 1,Product 2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like i got the solution.
I used low-level caching to achieve this.
Here we go;

```
def set_constants
  @main_contents = fetch_main_cache(MainContentsController, MainContent)
  @abouts = fetch_main_cache(AboutsController, About)
  @products = fetch_main_cache(ProductsController, Product)
  @services = fetch_main_cache(ServicesController, Service)
  @policies = fetch_main_cache(PoliciesController, Policy)
  @comm = fetch_main_cache_with_query(CommunicationsController, Communication, 'first').first
end

def fetch_main_cache(controller, model)
  fetch_main_cache_with_query controller, model, 'all'
end

def fetch_main_cache_with_query(controller, model, query)
  Rails.cache.fetch(controller.controller_name + '_main_cache') do
    model.send query
  end
end

def clear_main_cache
  Rails.cache.delete controller_name + '_main_cache'
end
```

Then i cleared the cache when a new model is created or updated.(I did this on every controller)

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @communication.update(communication_params)
      clear_main_cache
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need that data everywhere it is fine to load them in the ApplicationController.

You could improve the performances using low-level cache on the queries using [Rails.cache.fetch](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching).

You can enable caching temporary in development using `rails dev:cache` command.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering i used this method before you answer tho.
I'll share what i did in a sec.